# Find paths that cover all edges between two nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, edges

we hope you are able to help us with the following problem:

A directed graph that may contain cycles is given. One has to find a set of paths that fulfill the following criterion:

all edges that can be passed on the way from node A to node B must be covered by the paths within the set (one edge can be part of more than one paths from the set)

the solution does not have to be necessarily the one with the lowest number of paths and the paths does not have to be necessarily the shortest ones. However, the solution should be efficiently implementable using a programming language just as java. We need the solution to generate a few test cases and it is important to cover all edges between a node A and a node B.

does everyone know a suitable algorithm? or does no efficient solution exist?

thanks a lot in advance for your advise! (we have already searched for a solution, but the one we found was focused on shortest paths and were extremely inefficient)

Here is a graphical representation of our problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIY34.jpg

Comment: Meaning you just need a path between node A and node B and it is not necessarily the shortest path? just use DFS algorithm then ,, but WHY are you looking for trouble finding longer paths and possibly a slower run time?

Comment: Can a path visit a vertex more than once?

Comment: @CME64: If you read the question you see OP is looking for a SET of paths from A to B, that touch as many unique edges as possible.

Comment: thanks for your reply! We need a set of paths that cover all edges that can be traversed on the way from a node A to a node B. The focus lies on the covering-aspect: at the end we need to get a set of paths in which every edge is considered at least one time. About the longer paths: We thought that it would make the solution finding easier if we mention that the redundancies within this set of paths does not have to be minimal.

Comment: you mean cover as many edges as possible ? or cover all possible paths in a series of solutions (all possibilities)?

Comment: To clarify - do you need *any* set that works, or the *smallest* set that works?

Answer (score 0):

Consider all edges *R(A)* reachable from *A*. They can be found by adding a node on each edge (i.e. turning each edge *U->V* to *U->X->V*) and then perform a Breadth First Search starting from *A*.

Edges outside of *R(A)* clearly cannot be be on a path from *A* to *B*, since then they'd be reachable from *A*. So all paths to B must go through edges of *R(A)*.

So the set of edges, *U*, we want to "cover" are all edges of *R(A)* that *B* is reachable from.

Now we are looking for a set of paths S from A to B, which contains all edges of U.

A straightforward method is the following:

- Color all edges of *R(A)* black and set *S={ }*
- While there are black edges remaining:

  - Take a black edge  UV.
  - If *B* is reachable from *V*:

    - Construct a path *P = A -> ... -> U -> V -> ... -> B*
    - Color all edges of *P* as gray
    - Add *P* to *S*
  - Else:

    - Color UV as gray.
- Then return S

As @user189 pointed out, if we consider reachable edges from A that go through B, we are allowing paths that go twice through B. (I.e. a->b->c->g->f->e in the example image).
His suggested solution (removing the node B before computing R(A) ) fixes this.

Regarding  complexity:

*R(A)* can be computed in *O(|E|)* time and the paths from *A* to an edge *UV* in *R(A)* can be directly read from the BFS tree. To check for reachability to *B* from *V* and to find the path, we can use a BFS tree starting from B and following edges backwards,  computed in *O(|E|)* time.

If we reference the paths implicitly through the edge UV that connects the two BFS trees, and use a O(1) read/update structure to maintain the set of black edges and to look up edges in the BFS trees, I think we can do this in *O(|E|)* time.

Comment: If I understood well, the edge "f" from the example will be in your set U. However we don't want to. Maybe we should delete the B node when computing R(A).

Comment: @user189: Correct! Although technically this gives a path from A to B, it goes through B twice (see edited), which is what OP does not want. (See edited answer).

Comment: I wonder if there are efficient approaches to this problem. Any idea for the complexity of your method/comparing to others?

Comment: This may in general result in paths that visit a vertex twice.  E.g. delete edges d, e and f in the example graph: now your solution would include a path that goes via edges h and i, even though this visits vertex 3 twice.  This is possibly what the OP wants, although that's unclear at this stage (I've asked for clarification, but haven't yet received any).

Comment: The node 3 is visited twice in the example, too. So I guess it is OK.

Comment: @user189: But in the original example, there is no *individual path* in which node 3 is visited twice.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Good point, I guess we need a clarification from OP.